# Telerik RadListView - how to access template controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, telerik

I am using RadListView control with some check boxes and text boxes in the item template. I am wondering if it is possible to access the check boxes and text boxes using javascript? I can set up the RadListView as an object in javascript but I am not sure how to access controls in the various templates.

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="CodeBlock1" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var listView = null;
    function GetPatternList() {
        listView = $find("<%=Me.rlvShiftPatterns.ClientID %>");
    }

</script>

</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

I want to get the value from a check box and then set a value in the text box depending on if the check box is checked or not.

Comment: Is it compulsory to accomplish this client-side? You may assign an identifier such as a class in the item template and perform your logic in jQuery/JavaScript by using an appropriate client-side event.

Comment: I would prefer client side, but not mandatory. I will give the class identifier a go.

Comment: If you need to find a control server-side, for example in the `ItemCommand` event, you can do so like this, where `e` is your event argument: `var checbox = (Checkbox)e.ListViewItem.FindControl("checkbox");`